# should an angular component check for the validity of it's input?

Tags: angularjs

This is a more general question.

I created a filter that should do the following:

take a number that is on one or two digits, and return the number on two digits

```
angular.module('myModule').filter('twoDigits', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return ('0' + input).slice(-2);
    };
});
```

I use form validation to make sure that what goes in is a number between 0 and 99.

But I know that my filter will act goofy if i put a null value in, or a string etc.

When I'm designing an angular component. 
Should I control what goes in from within the logic of the component ?

Or should I just control the input from outside (like with form validation).

Comment: Where are you using this filter? Also why are you using it? Is it purely visual reasons or do you need it in a 2 digits format to work programmatically?

Comment: It' for visual reasons. For a timer on two digits.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is usually best to do some form of validation in real-time while the user is filling out a form AND to do form validation on the backend when the server processes the data.

Validation on the front end makes the user experience better because it reduces the amount of errors that may come back after the user thinks they have entered in all the required information, only to find out something was in the wrong format and they have to try again until they get it right.

Validation on the backend reduces vulnerabilities that you may not be aware of (forms SQL injection) as well as protects against any headaches you may run into such as when a user tries to put a dash (-) in a phone number entry that only allows numbers (or certain number of characters, etc). Also there are always ways to get around the front end validation, via javascript tweaking in the console that will technically allow the user to enter in data without filtering through the front-end validation.

It is always best practice to validate on the front and back.